# Create stopmotion video with ffmpeg - error while rendering

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, rendering

I'm currently creating a stopmotion video with the help of ffmpeg and some scripts I've made. Although in the last clip I attempted to render I had a couple of frames which I've edited. The method I'm using has worked before so I'm certain that it has to do with GIMP changing something with the files. I work with .png-images. This is the command and the output I get:

ffmpeg -sameq -f image2 -r 7 -i "$src_dir/frame-%06d.png" -r 25 "$dest_dir/$file_name.avi"

output:

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.1-4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 22 2012 05:09:06 with gcc 4.6.3
This program is not developed anymore and is only provided for compatibility. Use avconv instead (see Changelog for the list of incompatible changes).
Input #0, image2, from '/mnt/storage/selected_frames/005-Middag-Animation/frame-%06d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:02.85, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: png, bgra, 1280x720, 7 fps, 7 tbr, 7 tbn, 7 tbc
File '/mnt/storage/Videoklipp//005-Middag-Animation.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Incompatible pixel format 'bgra' for codec 'mpeg4', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
[buffer @ 0x1b88860] w:1280 h:720 pixfmt:bgra
[avsink @ 0x1b8a480] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x1b8ab80] w:1280 h:720 fmt:bgra -> w:1280 h:720 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
Output #0, avi, to '/mnt/storage/Videoklipp//005-Middag-Animation.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf53.21.0
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 2 kb/s, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
[buffer @ 0x1b88860] Changing frame properties on the fly is not supported.
    Last message repeated 6 times
frame=   13 fps=  0 q=0.0 Lsize=     524kB time=2.20 bitrate=1951.2kbits/s    
video:517kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.323318%
```

"[buffer @ 0x1b88860] Changing frame properties on the fly is not supported"

What can I do to fix this? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Don't use `-sameq`. It doesn't mean "same quality", and you're applying it as an input option which isn't typical convention. Use `-qscale` instead with a value of 2-5. You can use ffmpeg to compare the original and gimped images: `ffmpeg -i frame-003582.png -i frame-004286.png`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to LordNeckbeard's comment I noticed that ffmpeg had split the video into png's with the color space "bgra" and GIMP saved png's with "rgb24". What I did to solve this was to run a batch job from The GIMP (Filters -> Batch -> Batch Process...) and loaded all the images which I wanted in the same video (the edited and the unedited) and chose to flatten the images so a change were performed and save the images, making them all use rgb24.

Then I could run the command to make the video successfully (with -qscale 1 instead of -sameq as LordNeckbeard suggested).

Thank you!